# problem accessing check-boxes values in some installations

Tags: php

I have following structure for check-boxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reg_field['first_name']" value="1" /> First Name<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="reg_field['last_name']" value="1" /> Last Name<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="reg_field['paypal_email']" value="1"/> PayPal Email<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="reg_field['website_url']" value="1" /> Website URL<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="reg_field['address']" value="1"/> Address<br />
```

For some installation, I can access these fields as

```
$reg_new_values = (isset($_POST['reg_field'])?$_POST['reg_field']:array());

echo $reg_new_values["'first_name'"]
```

but for some installation, it won't work at all?

Is my structure wrong, or do I have to change some settings in PHP.INI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name to something like this `reg_field[first_name]` instead of `reg_field['first_name']`. Remove the single quotes, by doing that you can access each field name as:

```
$FirstName = $_POST['reg_field']['first_name'];
```